# SelfSSL in IIS 6.0

Tags: security, iis, ssl, iis-6

I am using IIS 6.0 and selfSSL to create a self signed certificate, but it only lasts one week.  How do I prolong the time of this?

Answer (score 0):

use the

/V:duration-of-validity 
Specifies the duration for which the certificate is valid. The default is 7 days.

SELFSSL [/T] [/N:cn] [/K:keylength] [/V:duration-of-validity] [/S:site-id] [/P:port] [/Q]